# Simple MakeFile Issue (missing separator)

Tags: c, macos, makefile

I am working on a small microcontroller project and ran into a problem compiling the source code with the makefile, linked below as well as the error:

```
      makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

[The makefile is found here. Click Me.](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FK6/1AKF/ANLEUN334H7/FK61AKFANLEUN334H7.txt)

Now why is it giving an error at line 1? It all looks fine to me but Apparently its not happy about something.
And yes, I checked to make sure it had proper tabs instead of spaces ;)

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.8.4. Can anybody point out where the problem lies?

Comment: If you had googled the error message, you could have found quickly that probably you used spaces instead of `<tab>`s.

Comment: I just tried that makefile on OS X 10.8.5 and I didn't have any issues. That being said, I wouldn't be surprised if the  `ö` character on line 1 was the root of your issue.

Comment: I can't help noticing that the m at the beginning of that error message is lowercase. Most people use `Makefile` with a capital M, but `make` recognizes both - and prefers the lowercase `makefile` if both are present. Are you sure it's reading the Makefile you wanted it to read?

Comment: Check your line endings.

Comment: Where did you get this makefile? Who or what last modified it?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: on a Mac, the file system is case-insensitive (but case-preserving) by default, so `Makefile` and `makefile` are the same file in any given directory.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment on the first line there is a "�" character, whose raw bytes include "0x0A" (a new-line).  It seems that `make` isn't aware of the file's input encoding and thinks that the line ends there; this means everything beyond this character is "no longer a comment", leading to errors.